# Chef - running remote SSH commands

Tags: ruby, ssh, chef-infra, heredoc

How could I go about running remote SSH commands using Chef? For example, bringing the following command into a recipe

```
ssh -T user@host.com <<'ENDSSH'
cat /etc/*-release
ENDSSH
```

Using the `execute` resource

```
execute "some_resource" do
  command "ssh -T user@host.com <<'ENDSSH'
  cat /etc/*-release
  ENDSSH"
  action :run
end
```

Results in

```
warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `ENDSSH')
```

I haven't tried using `bash` with `ENDSSH`, however. Using `EOT` seems to conflict with the outer `EOH` expected when using the `bash` resource. Would this be possible using Chef, or would something along the lines of `Mixlib::ShellOut` be more suitable to work around either indentations being added or parsed out by Chef when using `HEREDOC` which I assume is the cause? In either case, stability seems questionable.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? This isn't likely to be a good place to use Chef compared to other tools.

Comment: I'm actually trying to remotely restore a config on an instance running FreeBSD and due to compliance needs, chef-client can't be installed on this particular node.

Comment: As you can probably see from my post history I'm quite a Chef booster, but for something like this I would look elsewhere. Salt (w/ salt-ssh), Ansible, or Fabric/Invoke would be a better fit and a lot less painful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @coderanger has the best answer in the comments ("you almost certainly shouldn't be doing this with Chef"), but just for completeness' sake, I believe the newlines in your string aren't being properly escaped.  Try something like this:

```
execute "some_resource" do
  command <<-HEREDOC
    ssh -T user@host.com <<\'ENDSSH\'
      cat /etc/*-release
    ENDSSH
  HEREDOC
end
```

Comment: Thanks @jayhendren, this wound up working and I agree, if stdout and/or exit codes are needed to inspect and continue a run, this may not be a very good approach. In my situation, I simply needed to scp a config file and issue a few reload commands. I would argue that if the commands being run are more or less autonomous to the rest of the recipe, this is acceptable to use.